# Apache shiro always creates a session in Login page (before a succesfull log-in)

Tags: session, shiro

good morning.

I don't know how to avoid this issue: Apache Shiro always creates a new session on every login page request. The behaviour I need is to create a session only after a successful log-in because on the contrary we have a security issue if on every login page request we have a new session.

Searching in Stakoverflow I found a similar issue and the proposal to solve this problem was to configure shiro.ini like this:

```
/login = authc
/logout = noSessionCreation, logout
/** = noSessionCreation, anon
```

But I've tried that and other configurations with no success.

Is there a solution to avoid this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much.